# Inserting text into a text file

Tags: linux, file, file-io

Alright, this maybe the simplest (or the stupidest) question, but I just got to know...

Suppose I have a text file containing account no. and balance. I am writing a program to search the file using entered account no. and update the balance field in the same text file with a new balance.
I am finding it surprisingly difficult to do so using file streams. The problem is that I am trying to overwrite the *balance* string in the said text file with a new *balance* string.

So, if the balance is 1000 (4 digits), I can overwrite it with another 4 digit string. But, if the new balance string is more than 4 digits, it is overwriting the data after the balance field (it is a simple text file mind you...).
For example, if the text file contains

```
Acc. No.         balance
123456           100
123567           2500
```

The fields are separated by TAB '\t' character, and next record is separated by  a newline '\n'. If I enter new deposit of 200000 for account 123456, the fwrite() function overwrites the data in the text file as...

```
Acc. No          Balance
123456           2001003567         2500
```

You can notice that the '\n' after the balance field, and 2 digits from the next accounts' acc. no. is overwritten.

Of course, no-one wants that to happen :)
What I need is a way to *insert* text in that file, not just *overwrite* it. There are many results of doing this using Java, python or even SED, but nothing using FILE streams.
Please share your thoughts... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to manage your data in a plain text file:

While you are reading the file in, write a modified version of your data into a temporary file, then delete the original file and rename the temp file to the original filename. But be carefull that no other process accesses the same file concurrently.

Database systems were invented for such purposes. So I recommend to manage your data in a database table and dynamically create a text report when needed.

Comment: But won't this end up in losing the original file modification/creation date ? I mean, it's not a problem to me, but database systems must need that date information, right ?

Comment: A database system per se doesn't need such date information. It's up to you to design your database accordingly. E.g. you can include a column to your table containing the timestamp of the last modification.

Comment: As _Vanje_ advised, I created a temporary file, edited it, then deleted the original. I did not like it, but it did work :) . But yes, I feel the database approch is definitely more efficient. But still wndering hoe _database_ does it in the first place..., they must be using the files too. Anyway...thnks guys

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to move all data after the insertion point a few bytes up first. That's what Java, sed or python do as well, if they aren't writing a temporary file to begin with.

Comment: You mean I have to read all the data into a buffer, write my data, and then write-back all the read data to the file. There is no way to insert data in-between the existing data ?

Comment: You don't have to keep them in memory all the time, you can jump to the end of the file, read a chunk, write it out a few bytes later on, read a chunk, and so on. However, yes, you have to move the data physically, one way or the other.